# UWP - navigation to a page based on the screen size

Tags: win-universal-app, visualstatemanager, uwp-xaml

I have a Windows 8.1 app which I am trying to convert to W10 universal platform. In 8.1 version of the app, I have a page where I show a list of items having some preview. And when any item form the list is clicked/tapped, I navigate to the detail page of that item (please note that the detail is a separate page not a control). Now, in UWP, I want the behaviour to be different on different screen sizes. For phones, I would still like to retain the 8.1 behavior. But for tablets and desktops, I would like to show the detail on the right side of the screen (without navigating away). I know if the detail was a control I could have used Visual State Manager to adjust the position of the detail control based on the screen size. But since it's a separate page (I already have the code from 8.1 so wanted to reuse the same), is there any way I can do it in UWP based on the screen size? Or the only way is to convert the detail page into a user control and do it with Visual State Manager?

Comment: You can check the screensize and navigate right?

Comment: But, on desktop or tablet, I need to show the same page on right side of the screen. I think it does not make any sense what I am trying to achieve here :) Because I cannot obviously show two pages side by side. So maybe only option is to create a control out of the detail page and set the column of the detail control based on the screen size.

Comment: Well that's something new I got to know today :) Can you please throw some sample code where similar kind of situation is being handled using Visual State Manager?

Comment: Check out the [Master-Detail sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail) which adapts to screen size in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: Awesome. I think this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: So basically I have to have the exact same xaml in the DataTemplate to show the detail on right side in case of bigger screens. I am thinking why not create a separate control then (out of the detail page) and use it in both the cases (narrow state and default state).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer, but could help you with more options.

You have the option of doing device-family layouts. It's more work, since you'll be replicating more of your xaml, but it gives you the freedom to completely replace the views from mobile to desktop to Xbox etc.

Basically, there are 3 ways to do this: 
http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/

Comment: Nice article. Thanks. Actually, my xaml would be exactly the same in all platforms (I mean at least the list of the items). It's just showing the detail (either via navigating to the different page or showing it on right side of the screen) which is going to be different based on the screen sizes. So I am not sure how using the device family layouts will help in this situation.

Comment: I was just thinking that you could basically swap out the view on mobile devices, which also lets you choose a different viewmodel - but yeah, I knew my answer would be thin. For what you're describing, there really is no other option than to go with the Visual State Manager I guess.

Comment: Yeah, so Visual State Manager would provide me with the option to adjust the position of any control based on the screen size (like in a grid I can set the grid.column of items list and the detail control to 0 on phone and 0/1 in tablet). But in my case, detail is a separate page (not a control), so I am not able to get it to work with Visual State Manager as well. I am not too good with xaml I have to admit :)